# How to make series with a given array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, series, string-concatenation

I am a VB.Net user. I would like to make an array as per below

```
Dim QRList() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50}
```

into a series as per below

```
1 - 4,
9 - 9,
12 - 16,
41 - 42,
44 - 44,
48 - 50,
```

I have tried the code below. But it doesn't work.

```
Dim QRList() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50}
Dim QRCount As Integer = QRList.Length
Dim startIndex, startN, endN As Integer

For i As Integer = 0 to QRCount - 1
    startindex = 0
    i = startindex
    startN = QRList(i)
    Do
        If startindex = QRCount - 1 Then
            endN = QRList(i)
        ElseIf startindex < QRCount - 1 Then
            If QRList(i + 1) - QRList(i) + 1 = 1 Then
                endN = QRList(i + 1)
            ElseIf QRList(i + 1) - QRList(i) + 1 > 1 Then
                endN = QRList(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        startindex = i + 1
        Console.Writeline(CStr(startN) & " - " & CStr(endN) & vbNewLine)
    Loop While startindex < QRCount
Next
```

Hope anyone can help on this issue, Thanks.

Austin HO

Comment: *"it doesn't work"*. That is a wholly inadequate description of a problem. You need to be able to tell us EXACTLY how it doesn't work. To do that, you need to have debugged the code properly, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, examining the state at every step. You can then see exactly where and how the behaviour of the code differs from your expectation. When you do that, you may even be able to solve the problem for yourself.

Comment: Hi, forgive me as this is my first post in stackoverflow. The outcome of my code above is as per below.

`1 - 1

2 - 2

3 - 3

4 - 4

9 - 9

12 - 12

13 - 13

14 - 14

15 - 15

16 - 16

41 - 41

42 - 42

44 - 44

48 - 48

49 - 49

50 - 50`

I apologize for not clearly state my problem.

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. If your question is missing required information, edit the question to provide it. This may be your first time posting but the fact that you have no badges indicates that you rejected the prompt to take the site tour when you registered.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop fails at the first comparison: `If QRList(i + 1) - QRList(i) + 1 = 1`.
Since the condition is not met, the execution continues to the `endN = QRList(i)` assignment and exits the `for` loop entirely.

You can simplify this process a bit.
Since you need to generate sequences of contiguous numbers, you just need to determine the starting values - values in the original series that have a distance `> 1` - and a variable to store the value of the previous iteration, used to perform the comparison.

Here, I'm using a List of named tuples (`List(Of (StartValue As Integer, EndValue As Integer)`) to store the values in the series.
You can use a `List(Of String)`, or another type of collection, if that's preferable or named Tuples are not available

```
Dim QRList As Integer() = { 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4}
' Sort the array in case it's not already sorted
Array.Sort(QRList)

Dim maxDistance As Integer = 1
Dim seriesCount As Integer = -1

' Assign starting values that are less than ([Min Value] - [Max Distance])
Dim startValue As Integer = QRList(0) - (maxDistance + 1)
Dim previousValue As Integer = startValue

Dim series As New List(Of (StartValue As Integer, EndValue As Integer))()
For Each value As Integer In QRList
   ' The distance is less than or equal to the maximum: update the current item
    If (value - maxDistance) <= previousValue Then
        series(seriesCount) = (startValue, value)
    Else
        ' The distance is > maxDistance: add a new starting item
        startValue = value
        series.Add((value, value))
        seriesCount += 1
    End If
    previousValue = value
Next
```

To print the elements in the series:

```
For Each t In series
    Console.WriteLine($"{t.StartValue} - {t.EndValue}")
Next
```

With `maxDistance = 1`, the series are:

```
1 - 4
9 - 9
12 - 16
41 - 42
44 - 44
48 - 50
```

With `maxDistance = 4`, the series are:

```
1 - 4
9 - 16
41 - 50
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code works too. I'll keep this if the tuple is not available in my project. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect candidate for the [Yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/yield-statement) statement to return an `IEnumerable(Of String)`.  You can pass that resulting `IEnumerable(Of String)` to `String.Join()` to obtain the final result.

Here's a quick example:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim QRList() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50}
    Dim series As String = String.Join("," & vbCrLf, GetSeries(QRList))

    Console.WriteLine("Original: " & String.Join(", ", QRList))
    Console.WriteLine("Series:")
    Console.WriteLine(series)
    Console.Write("Press Enter to quit...")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Iterator Function GetSeries(ByVal values() As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim startNum, endNum As Integer?
    For Each value As Integer In values
        If Not startNum.HasValue Then
            startNum = value
            endNum = value
        ElseIf value = (endNum + 1) Then
            endNum = value
        Else
            Yield startNum & " - " & endNum
            startNum = value
            endNum = value
        End If
    Next
    Yield startNum & " - " & endNum
End Function
```

Producing the following output:

```
Original: 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50
Series:
1 - 4,
9 - 9,
12 - 16,
41 - 42,
44 - 44,
48 - 50
Press Enter to quit...
```

Just to make it extra clear what is happening, you can convert the iterator to an array like this:

```
Dim arrSeries() As String = GetSeries(QRList).ToArray
For i As Integer = 0 To arrSeries.Length - 1
    Console.WriteLine(i & ": " & arrSeries(i))
Next
```

Producing:

```
0: 1 - 4
1: 9 - 9
2: 12 - 16
3: 41 - 42
4: 44 - 44
5: 48 - 50
```

And, finally, if you need to work with the actual Integer start and stop values as a set, then simply convert the iterator function to return `IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer))` instead, and use this `Yield` statement in the function in both places:

```
Yield New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)(startNum, endNum)
```

Comment: Thank you, Idle_Mind. This help me a lot. It actually solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Glad it was helpful!  Be sure to upvote and/or accept all answers that helped you out.